# Upper bound for OEIS A076689 "Smallest k such that k*p#+1 is prime"?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, oeis

[OEIS A076689](https://oeis.org/A076689)

Is defined as smallest integer $a(n)=k$ such that $k n\#+1$ is prime,
where $n\#$ is primorial, the product of the first $n$ primes.

Lower bound appears $1$, the primorial primes.

> What is upper bound for $a(n)$, possibly using plausible conjectures?

By examining the B-file, it might as low as $Cn$.

---

Upper bound polynomial in $n$ might give fast *deterministic*
algorithm for finding large primes:  http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Finding_primes

Answer (score 2):

The answers to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80865/least-prime-in-a-arithmetic-progression) seem to indicate that there is an upper bound of the form $O(n^{2+\epsilon})$ for any $\epsilon$ (using the unpublished result of Oesterle). I am sure experts might say more (and this does not use the primoriality in any way).

Comment: Thanks. I suspect primorial is the best choice for low bound.

Comment: I edited with possible application of upper polynomial bound.

Comment: The $q$ in the linked answers is larger than $\exp(n)$.

Comment: @joro it's $n^n,$ thus the $\epsilon.$

Comment: How is it $n^n$? $\log{n\#}=\theta(p_n)\sim p_n$. Chebyshev theta.

Comment: Do you mean this result: $p \leq 70 q (\log q)^2$ under GRH? This indeed appears to give something close to your claim :)

Comment: Hm, the linked question require $q$ to be prime AFAICT.

Comment: @joro yes, $\log n \sim p_n \sim n \log n.$ As for $q$ being prime, I am not sure what the assumptions of Oesterle's alleged results are, but I don't see where the primality would matter...

Comment: I suspect the same too. Btw, you appear to have typo in your comment, likely missing/not escaping "#".

Comment: Citable reference even for $q$ prime might solve this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/217919/what-is-wrong-with-this-deterministic-algorithm-efficiently-generating-large-pri

Comment: You appear to cite quite controversial result -- check the comments in the answer you link to. Some claim this is not proved... And the second best bound doesn't appear good for me.