# Asymptotic number of "modular primes"

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics

We can say that a number $p$ is prime modulo $N$ if for any two numbers $1<a,b<p$, $ab \not\equiv p \pmod N$. We will define $p(n)$ to be the number of primes mod $n$. I'm wondering about the asymptotic value of $p(n)$. If $p \leq \sqrt n$ then $p$ is prime modulo $n$ iff it's prime, so $p(n) = \Omega(\frac {\sqrt n} {\log n})$. Experimentally I get that the ratio $\frac {p(n)}{\sqrt n}$ varies around 0.5. Is $p(n) = \Theta(\sqrt n)$? Does $\frac {p(n)}{\sqrt n}$ converge? To what? What about $\frac 1n \sum_{i=2}^n \frac {p(i)}{\sqrt i}$? For 10000 it's about 0.51, and for 9000 0.515. A possible approach I've thought about is to prove that for every $d, x$, the number of $n \leq x$ modulo which $d$ is prime is $O(\frac{x\sqrt x}d)$, which gives a bound of $O(\sqrt x \log \log x)$ on average. I believe this can be done using sieve methods like [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/188094/498835), but it seems like the proof there only gives a bound of $O(\frac{x \root4\of x}{\sqrt d})$ which gives a bound of $O(x^\frac34)$ on average, and I don't know enough about sieve methods to improve on that.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69509/small-residue-classes-with-small-reciprocal .  I think Kloosterman sum methods may be able to show that such primes modulo $n$ must be of size $O(n^{3/4})$ (at least if $n$ is prime), but this is almost certainly suboptimal.

Comment: If you type `a\equiv b(\mod c)` you see $a\equiv b(\mod c),$ and if you type `a\equiv b\pmod c` you see $a\equiv b\pmod c.$ I edited this question so that that latter form is used. (If more than one object is to be included in the parenthesis, then you need curly braces `{ }`, thus: `a\equiv b\pmod{cd}` gives you $a\equiv b\pmod{cd}.  \qquad$

Comment: I am confused about this last claim. Isn't the number of mod-$n$ primes up to $\sqrt{n\log n}$ at most the number of primes up to $\sqrt{n\log n}$ and therefore at most $\approx \sqrt{n/log n}$ by the prime number theorem? So the claim that these are all but $O(1)$ contradicts the claim that the number of mod-$n$ primes should be comparable to $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Suppose $p$ is much smaller than $n$. Then to be a mod-$n$ prime, $p$ must be prime and the numbers $cn+p$ must have no divisors in the range $( \frac{cn+p}{p}, p ) \approx ( \frac{cn}{p} ,p) $ for all $1 \leq  c \leq \frac{p(p-1)}{n} $. The average number of divisors in that range is $\log \frac{p^2}{cn}$. The range is symmetric so the number of divisors is even, and if the statistics are otherwise Poissonian then the probability of having no divisors in that range is $e ^{ - \frac{1}{2} \log \frac{p^2}{cn} }= \frac{ \sqrt{cn}}{p}$.

Comment: So we might heuristically estimate that the probability that $p$ is a mod $n$ prime is $\frac{1}{\log p} \prod_{ c \leq \frac{p^2}{n}} \frac{ \sqrt{cn}}{p} $ and note that $\prod_{ c \leq \frac{p^2}{n}} \frac{ \sqrt{cn}}{p} $ is a continuous function of $\frac{p^2}{n}$ which is integrable, which suggests we get a constant times $\frac{ \sqrt{n}}{\log n}$. I guess this is further from your empirical data than the $(1- \frac{1}{n})^{p^2}$ heuristic, even though it's ``more sophisticated" since it keeps track of sizes of potential divisors. Probably the Poissonian assumption is not so good.

Comment: @WillSawin I added my analysis, and I think the discrepancy is just due to my heuristic being bad with small numbers (it estimates the probability they're prime as much closer to 1 than it actually is). The heuristic you suggested is equal to $\frac1{\log p} (\frac{\sqrt n}p)^{\lfloor \frac{p^2}n\rfloor} \sqrt{\lfloor \frac{p^2}n\rfloor!}$, right? Empirically $\frac{\sqrt n}{\log n}$ does seem like a worse fit than $\sqrt n$.

Comment: If I directly evaluate $\sum_{p=2}^n {\frac1{\log p}(\frac{\sqrt n}p)^{\lfloor \frac{p^2}n \rfloor} \sqrt{\lfloor \frac{p^2}n \rfloor !}}$ it does seem like a better fit (the average ratio was ~0.95).